# Are all bury attacks equal?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Just curious if the time you're stuck in a bury is the same for all attacks that cause you to be buried, or the amount of mashing needed to get out is the same?

Examples include:

- G&W down smash
- KKR's down throw
- DK's side special
- Wii Fit trainer's neutral normal 3-hit combo
- Pitfall items
- etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you haven't heard of [Beefy Smash Dudes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeCEq4Sz1nNK4wn3Z4Ozk2w), I highly suggest checking them out. They have some amazing technical Smash content, and they're always my go to for keeping up with new Smash techniques. Not to mention they just [put out a video on Smash Ultimate buries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWsCApe4e94) 4 days ago!

To sum up, each burying attack has a "base duration." In other words, **not all bury attacks are created equal.** From the video linked above, here are the base bury times (in seconds) for different moves at 0% without mashing:

[image]

The more percent a buried character has, the longer they'll stay buried. But just from this graphic it's clear that *some* buries are many times more powerful than others (looking at you, Inkling).

Mashing will help to shorten the time, but different mashes will reduce the time different amounts. An input like <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> will reduce bury time by **.25 seconds** or 15 frames. Directional inputs on your control stick on the other hand, reduce the buy by half that of the buttons, or about **.13 seconds** or 8 frames (however, the game only counts the cardinal directions--up/down/left/right--as inputs on the stick). For more on the technicalities of mashing, see [Beefy's Smash 4 mashing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwfXtDiQA24), since the mechanic has remained the same in Ultimate.

Comment: Just a question -- it seems PItfall items didn't get listed, do you know how long that effect lasts?

Comment: @senpai after a quick test in training mode it looks like it’s **just over 10.5 seconds** with no mash at 0% on Palitena (same conditions as were tested with in the video).

Comment: @scohe001 which bury has the longest duration? is it the Pitfall?

Comment: @BlazingTrio I didn't test the other items that were mentioned in the video, but it looks like the Pitfall item has the longest bury (which makes sense, since that's its sole job). The longest character bury appears to be the Inkling Splat Roller and the Zero Suit Flip Kick.

Answer (score -1):

In previous games, bury time is purely based on knockback dealt (as in the amount of knockback that would have been applied if it weren't a bury attack). In Ultimate, it appears to also be based on current damage (though less so). The exact formula isn't known yet.

Each input of mashing reduces bury time by 8 frames.

Comment: Since knockback is based on the move's base knockback and the percent of the player getting hit, isn't it safe to say that previous games' bury times were also based on percent? Especially with different moves burying for different times in Ultimate, it seems that bury in this game bury time may also be based on "the amount of knockback that would have been applied if it weren't a bury attack."

Comment: The implication is that moves that deal fixed knockback still vary in bury time based on the victim's damage, which is not the case in previous games.

Comment: Ahh I forgot about fixed knockback moves, good call.